# Polymer paper dropdown menu button shrinking

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm new to polymer and using version 1.0, and I'm having same problems with the paper dropdown menu button.

Every time I click on it, its height gets smaller.

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">

    <style>
        html,body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #EFFBFB;
            font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
        <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div class="app-name">Dashbord</div>
            <span class="flex"></span>
            <paper-menu-button horizontal-align="right" horizontal-offset="20" vertical-align="top" vertical-offset="50" height="100%">
            <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
                <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
                <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
       </paper-menu-button>
    </paper-toolbar>

    <div class="horizontal-section-container">
        <div class="horizontal-section">

            <paper-menu>
                    <paper-item><iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon>  Inbox</paper-item>
                <paper-item><iron-icon icon="send" item-icon></iron-icon>  Outbox</paper-item>
                <paper-item><iron-icon icon="delete" item-icon></iron-icon>  Trash</paper-item>
                <paper-item><iron-icon icon="report" item-icon></iron-icon>  Spam</paper-item>

            </paper-menu>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Another thing is that the demo hse the same problem to.

Do I need to reinstall somthing? chang my imports?

Thanks.

Comment: hey, fixed the problem. I was using an old version of chrome... updated to the newest one - and the problem solevd!